# Enumerate all files of certain type from resources

Tags: java, resources, java-web-start

I have a JAR file which is included in resources section of my JNLP file. This contains lots of images in subfolders.

The user should be able to substitute this JAR file later on to add/remove images.

Is there a way to enumerate all files from the resources with, lets say .GIF as file extension or even better to specify a pattern like "images/*.gif" (so I just get images which have "images" as their parent directory).

The other option would be to write a text file that reflects the file structure. This way you can run through it line by line, image by image but this would mean you have to update two places and this is not very user-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you just grab the jar and move to the directory then enumerate the files inside:

```
public String[] getFiles() throws IOException {
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<JarEntry> ents = new ArrayList<JarEntry>();
   Enumeration<JarEntry> e = null;

   URL jarp = getLocation();
   if (jarp != null) {
    jar = jarp.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("jar") ? jarp : new URL("jar:" +                                                                                                                                                                                      jarp.toString() + "!/");
    JarFile jarf = null;
    try {
        jarf = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedExceptionAction<JarFile>() {

                    @Override
                    public JarFile run() throws Exception {
                        JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection) jar.openConnection();
                        conn.setUseCaches(false);
                        return conn.getJarFile();
                    }
                });
    } catch (PrivilegedActionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LicenseLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    e = jarf.entries();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry je = e.nextElement();
        if (!je.isDirectory()) {
            ents.add(je);
        }
    }
    for (JarEntry ent : ents) {
        if ((ent.getName().startsWith(pathName)) && (ent.getName().endsWith(".gif"))) {
            String name = ent.getName().replace(pathName, "");
            list.add(name);
        }
    }
 }
 return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```